# XAMPP apache server not using the ports I desire, not certain why

Tags: apache, xampp, port, virtualhost

So, I've been setting up this HTTP server for a school project that has to be able to maintain multiple domains through virtual hosts. Using XAMPP I have my server set up, I thought I'd done it properly but perhaps not.

I had heaps of issues with not being able to listen to a port, to solve this I used (in httpd.conf under apache/conf/)

```
    Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
    ServerName localhost:8080
```

If I used 80/81/8080/321/any combination that did not have the prefix 0.0.0.0 it told me the port could not be listened or whatever (sorry, a little rusty with my syntax).

I set up my first virtual host up like so (under apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf):

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot    "H:/xampp2/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName      localhost:8080

    <Directory "H:/xampp2/xampp/htdocs">
        Option Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I thought this seemed all good and well and I don't believe I've modified anything else. To me, I would expect that this means my Apache server would use port 8080 for the server? However, when I start Apache in XAMPP it states quite clearly

```
 Apache started [Port 80]
```

Why would this be port 80?

In conjunction, localhost:8080 doesn't navigate me to the documents, but localhost:80 or localhost do. I presume that this just means it's still on port 80. I've tried resetting my computer and XAMPP.

If you need any more information, please let me know. I tried following guides such as this one: http://ailoo.net/2008/07/set-up-multiple-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-for-windows/

Cheers.

Oh, I also edited my Windows HOSTS file; it looks like so:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       localhost:8080
```

Edit: New error... Now getting this when I init, doesn't seem to be affecting it though:

```
 ERROR: Status Check Failure [3]
 This program must be run from your XAMPP root directory.
```

It is being run from teh root directory as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok Im not advanced in this area either. However after much playing around with XAMPP and following a few different guides I got mine working.

The Host under drivers seems abit weird. I declared mine as:

```
 127.0.0.1:8080    test.localhost.com
 127.0.0.1:8080    test2.localhost.com
```

Back up you Xampp, then extract a clean install to C: - Just because that Status check failure sounds like bad news.

!Remember to run setup_xampp.bat from the xampp directory and install the apache service!

Then under you httpd.conf add:

```
ServerRoot C:\xampp\apache
Listen 7070
Listen 8080
Listen 9090
```

Apache might not like that at first but meh.

The ServerRoot may already be declared above the Listen spot so just double check.

After that head to C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra.

Edit the httpd-vhosts.conf.

Under the section Name-based virtual hosting add:

```
NameVirtualHost *:7070
NameVirtualHost *:8080
NameVirtualHost *:9090
```

There will be a couple of examples of virtual hosts below that. Add:

```
<VirtualHost *:7070>
    DocumentRoot    "C:/xampp/www/YOURWEBSITEDIR1"
    ServerName      test.localhost.com
    <Directory "C://xampp/www/YOURWEBSITEDIR1">
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:9090>
    DocumentRoot    "C:/xampp/www/YOURWEBSITEDIR2"
    ServerName      test2.localhost.com
    <Directory "C://xampp/www/YOURWEBSITEDIR2">
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Not the double slash in the Directory tag. Now ensure there is an index.html under each of those directories. Restart the apache (Stop, start).

I cant navigate to the test.localhost.com URLs, probably due to the fact they are terribly wrong in the HOSTs config. Though I can connect to 127.0.0.1:7070, 127.0.0.1:9090 and access the webpages from there.

Also 127.0.0.1:8080 connects me to the xampp welcome panel that localhost used to connect you too.

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Sorry, just working through this now. Why note the double slash in the directory? Why have it? Out of curiosity, I can't see how it helps.

Comment: Just what works for me. This is exactly how I have set up and (terribly) run my apache. If anyone can correct me on it, please do.

Comment: Okay, I have tried doing all this several times now. The issue I am currently having is that it does not appear to be noticing that I have virtual hosts, in my opinion.

I can go directly to 127.0.0.1:8080, as you were able, and it will take me to xampp - which is what I'm pointing to in both my vhosts and httpd.conf files. Interesting to note that I could also not use the address in my HOSTS to get to the site; However back on topic, it seems to me as if it's not loading the vhosts properly as none of the other addresses can be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that saying 'listening on port 80' is hard-coded into XAMPP, regardless of the port you use. Thus, your code should work fine.
In my .conf file, it just says "listen 80" instead of   Listen 0.0.0.0:8080 
Cheers.

Comment: How does that answer the question..?

Comment: It helps, in that although XAMPP may say that it's only listening on port 80, you can troubleshoot more easily, knowing that this doesn't actually mean that it's only listening on port 80.